# How to connect to the Internet or Network from a Ubuntu virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a Virtual Machine on which I installed Ubuntu 10. I am not able to connect to the internet from the Ubuntu machine. Am I missing anything there ?

Comment: How did you set up the virtual network card?

Comment: I just left it default.

Comment: If you have left the default settings, it will be using NAT. Make sure Virtualbox is not being blocked in your firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VirtualBox select your virtual machine and click settings. Go to the Network section. Make sure that the "Enable Network Adapter" check box is checked. From there you can decide to connect through a NAT or Bridged...